# Drop down and Radio button List for string field in MVC 4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I have String field for Gender and Hospital Category in My MVC 4 (code First) Model Class. I want to have a radio button list for Gender showing Male and Female and Save "Male" or "Female" according to selection in my view instead of a text box which is added when generating the view. And for Hospital I want to show list of Hospital Categories in a d drop down, example, Government, Private etc. and the one selected will be saved to the Hospital Categories. I know if i use to have another class and make a relation by ID fields. but since i already have data in those fields and the application is running, I was looking for any shortcut. please help me.

Model class:

```
    public class MedicalDetail
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string CaseNo
    {
        get
        {
            if (this.RimsMain != null)
                return this.RimsMain.CaseNoNew;
            else
                return "N/A";
        }
    }
    [Required]
    [ForeignKey("RimsMain")]
    public int RimsMainId { get; set; }
    public virtual RimsMain RimsMain { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:d}")]
    [Column(TypeName = "DateTime2")]
    public DateTime Dob { get; set; }
    public string Nationality { get; set; }
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:d}")]
    [Column(TypeName = "DateTime2")]
    [DisplayName("Examin Date")]
    public DateTime ExaminDate { get; set; }
    public string Gender { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Referred For Hospital")]
    public string ReferredForHospital { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Madicine Provided")]
    public string MadicineProvided { get; set; }
    public string Demand { get; set; }
    public string Reimbursement { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Milk Assistance")]
    public string MilkAssistance { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Chronic Case")]
    public string ChronicCase { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Special Case")]
    public string SpecialCase { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Gyne Case")]
    public string GyneCase { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Referred By UNHCR")]
    public bool ReferralByUNHCR { get; set; }
    [MaxLength]
    public string LabInvestigation { get; set; }
    [MaxLength]
    public string Diagnosis { get; set; }
    public string HospitalCategory { get; set; }
    [MaxLength]
    public string Recommendation { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Last Updated by")]
    public int? UserId { get; set; }
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:d}")]
    [Column(TypeName = "DateTime2")]
    [DisplayName("Last Updated")]
    public DateTime? LastUpdated { get; set; }
```

}

view:

```
        @model Rims.Models.MedicalDetail
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
}
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Medical Detail</legend>
        <h4 style="color:@ViewBag.Color;">@ViewBag.Message</h4>
        <div>
            <div class="col2">
                <div class="editor-label">
                    <label for="RimsMainId">Case No</label>
                </div>
                <div class="editor-field">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.RimsMain.CaseNoNew)
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.RimsMain.CaseNoNew)
                </div>
                <div class="editor-label">
                    <label for="Name">Name</label>
                </div>
                <div class="editor-field">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name)
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name)
                </div>
                <div class="editor-label">
                    <label for="Dob">DOB</label>
                </div>
                <div class="editor-field">
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Dob, new { @class = "form-control datepicker" })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Dob)
                </div>

                <div class="editor-label">
                    <label for="Nationality">Nationality</label>
                </div>
                <div class="editor-field">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Nationality)
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Nationality)
                </div>
                <div class="editor-label">
                    <label for="ExaminDate">Examin Date</label>
                </div>
                <div class="editor-field">
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.ExaminDate, new { @class = "form-control datepicker" })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ExaminDate)
                </div>

                <div class="editor-label">
                    <label for="Gender">Gender</label>
                </div>
                <div class="editor-field">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Gender)
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Gender)
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col2">
                <div>
                    <div class="editor-label">
                        <label for="ReferredFor">Referred by UNHCR</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="editor-field">
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ReferralByUNHCR)
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ReferralByUNHCR)
                    </div>
                    <div class="clear"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="editor-label">
                    <label for="MadicineProvided">Madicine Provided</label>
                </div>
                <div class="editor-field">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.MadicineProvided)
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.MadicineProvided)
                </div>
                <div class="editor-label">
                    <label for="MilkAssistance">Milk Assistance</label>
                </div>
                <div class="editor-field">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.MilkAssistance)
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.MilkAssistance)
                </div>
                <div class="editor-label">
                    <label for="MilkAssistance">Chronic Case</label>
                </div>
                <div class="editor-field">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ChronicCase)
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ChronicCase)
                </div>
                <div class="editor-label">
                    <label for="MilkAssistance">Special Case</label>
                </div>
                <div class="editor-field">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.SpecialCase)
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.SpecialCase)
                </div>
                <div class="editor-label">
                    <label for="MilkAssistance">Gyne Case</label>
                </div>
                <div class="editor-field">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.GyneCase)
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.GyneCase)
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="clear"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="editor-label">
            <label for="Demand">Demand</label>
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Demand, 5, 70, new { @class = "txtArea" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Demand)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-label">
            <label for="ReimbursemenT">Reimbursement</label>
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Reimbursement, 5, 70, new { @class = "txtArea" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Reimbursement)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-label">
            <label for="Referred">Referred for Hospital</label>
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.ReferredForHospital, 5, 70, new { @class = "txtArea" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ReferredForHospital)
        </div>
         <div class="editor-label">
            <label for="Remarks">Lab Investigation</label>
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.LabInvestigation, 5, 70, new { @class = "txtArea" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.LabInvestigation)
        </div>
         <div class="editor-label">
            <label for="Remarks">Diagnosis</label>
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Diagnosis, 5, 70, new { @class = "txtArea" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Diagnosis)
        </div>

         <div class="editor-label">
            <label for="Remarks">Hospital Category</label>
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.HospitalCategory, 5, 70, new { @class = "txtArea" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.HospitalCategory)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-label">
            <label for="Remarks">Recommendation</label>
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Recommendation, 5, 70, new { @class = "txtArea" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Recommendation)
        </div>

        <p id="otherButtons1">
            <input type="submit" value="Create" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
}
<div id="otherButtons">
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>
```

In the Above view I want to replace the the following Field by Two Radio Buttons that is Male and Female

```
<div class="editor-label">
                    <label for="Gender">Gender</label>
                </div>
                <div class="editor-field">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Gender)
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Gender)
                </div>
```

And The Following field by a drop down which will have some values. for example "Gov", "Private" etc.

```
 <div class="editor-label">
            <label for="Remarks">Hospital Category</label>
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.HospitalCategory, 5, 70, new { @class = "txtArea" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.HospitalCategory)
        </div>
```

also I want to know how can i save the value in Create Action:

```
[HttpPost]
        [Authorize(Roles = "Admin,Medical")]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Create(MedicalDetail medicaldetail)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                var rimsMain = db.RimsMains.Where(x => x.CaseNoNew == medicaldetail.RimsMain.CaseNoNew).FirstOrDefault();
                if (rimsMain == null)
                {
                    ViewBag.Message = "Invalid Case Number!";
                    ViewBag.Color = "Red";
                    return View(medicaldetail);
                }
                else
                {
                    medicaldetail.RimsMainId = rimsMain.Id;
                    //medicaldetail.RimsMain = rimsMain;
                    medicaldetail.LastUpdated = DateTime.Now;
                    medicaldetail.UserId = WebSecurity.CurrentUserId;
                    db.MedicalDetails.Add(medicaldetail);
                    db.SaveChanges();
                    return RedirectToAction("Create", new { message = "Record Added Successfully!", color = "Green" });
                }
            }

            return View(medicaldetail);
        }
```

Comment: not understanding your problem plz post code here...

Comment: you have to create Dropdown for Company List using Viewbag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Gender selection you need to use Radio buttons with same name ::

```
<input type="radio" name="Gender" value="Male"/>Male
<br/>
<input type="radio" name="Gender" value="Female"/>Female
```

and for Company list you should use viewbag as::

```
@Html.DropDownList("Company", "Select Company")
```

and on Server side the Viewbag will be formed as  ::

```
ViewBag.Company = new SelectList(context.Companies, "ID", "Name");
```

Comment: every thing worked well, but the Company drop down is not bound to the Field and thus it didn't save the value to db? can you please tell me how can i save it to database?

Comment: Company dropdown's value will be passed to the Server on Form submit. There you can write your logic to Save it into database.

Comment: I am not using FormCollection Object, instead I am Using the MedicalDetail Object, is there any way where i can still get the dropwodn value?

Comment: In that case you need to use @DropdownListFor(model=>model.CompanyList)

Comment: I tried DropdownListFor() as well but it was giving some kind of error. not sure what was that. but i worked out, by getting a Form Collection Method Along with the MedicalDetil Object. and it worked. thanks a lot.